# Why is the winter bashed themed as such when users of the network are from all around the world (and it's summer in half the Globe)?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

These aren't the geographically located Olympics. I am from the Southern Hemisphere and this makes me feel alienated, as sometimes occurs in other forums and communities. I think many people will share the feeling.

Comment: I live near the equater. What is this winter you speak of? :D

Comment: 'WinterInSomeLatitudeSomewhere Bash' does not have the same cachet..

Comment: Also see [Winter Bash in Summer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312750/4642212).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is known to the company; see for example this footnote to the [Winter Bash 2015 blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/12/14/announcing-winter-bash-2015/):

> 1: As in the past, tradition defeated accuracy in the naming decision. Hopefully some of our summertime audience will be at least partially mollified by the fact that the Winter Bash site will be available in Portuguese, Spanish, Japanese and Russian this year, thanks to the efforts of our international Community Managers.

Unfortunately, [you're in the minority](https://sciencing.com/differences-between-northern-southern-hemisphere-8260091.html), and it's IMHO not likely to be changed. At least you have good weather to pair with the Bash...

Comment: (copied from [another answer of mine](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32895/228959); I think it applies here as well)

Comment: I guess Northcentrism is the new Eurocentrism. Nice of the site to put itself in the wrong side of history